# Specifying that a column should just be inserted not upserted

Tags: node.js, objection.js

I have some data i want to insert via `insertGraph`
ala `ModelName
       .query(trx)
       .insertGraph(data)`
 problem is I have a guard with `allowInsert` that specifies which columns should be populated. I have a column holding a foreign key to another table. I don't want this column to be populated. I keep getting `trying to upsert an unallowed relation`. I'm at a loss on how to specify that `foreignId` shouldn't be populated.
My code looks like this with the `allowInsert` guard

```
ModelName
       .query(trx)
       .allowInsert([subrelation2.[columnToPopulate1, columnToPopulate2]])
       .insertGraph(data)
```

P.s. I've tried specifying `foreignId` in the `allowInsert` condition to no avail. Specifying `relation2.*` allows the insertion. But I want to retain the sanity checks

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are specifying columns of the `relation2` model, instead of subrelations. Is `columnToPopulate1` a subrelation of the Model of `relation2`? By the name looks like a column of the model, which is wrong.

I think that you want to use a relations to insert two columns in the 'relation2' model. Something like:

```
let data = {
  modelNameColumn: 'value',
  relation2: {
    columnToPopulate1: 'value',
    columnToPopulate2: 'value',
  }
}

await ModelName
   .query(trx)
   .allowInsert('[relation2]')
   .insertGraph(data)
```

In `allowInsert` method you can only specify which relations are allowed to be inserted, but cant define which columns.

In case you want to remove the posibility of a column to be updated, you can use a `beforeUpdate()` trigger:

```
class Model2 extends Model {
  async $beforeUpdate(opt, queryContext) {
    await super.$beforeUpdate(opt, queryContext);
    if (this.columnName) throw new Error('columnName shouldnt be updated')
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect that `relation2` is indeed a `subrelation`. `[columnToPopulate1, columnToPopulate2]` are also subrelations of `relation2` and get inserted. The problem is the data im trying to insert comes with an id that is to serve as a foreign key `foreignId`, because of what is specified in `allowInsert` i cannot insert this id into the table

Comment: And you want to keep the provided id by the client?

Comment: `relation2` looks like this `foreignKey, rId, columnToPopulate1, columnToPopulate2`. I want to insert an id into `foreignkey` and populate `columnToPopulate*`

Comment: Its difficult to understand. Maybe show your database structure and desired behaviour. Cant help with this information